# Issue in Get Deploy URL in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I need to know about the below shown issue when i get this issue is tries to get `localhost:3000` and the server console contains no errors.I didn't get any idea about this.So can you please suggest me what to do?

I hope to think get error is the below shown code:

```
Template.content.helpers

({
    'renderTemplate': function()

    {
       if(Session.get('ContentTemplate') == undefined)

       {
         Session.set('ContentTemplate', 'main');

       }

        return new Handlebars.SafeString(Template[Session.get('ContentTemplate')]({dataKey: '0'}));

    }

 })
```

Please check once and how to write the above code is in updated 0.8 version.

```
[23:41:40.071] The connection to ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/779/12_lsxfc/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading. @ http://localhost:3000/packages/livedata.js?7f11e3eaafcbe13d80ab0fb510d25d9595e78de2:1338
[23:41:40.080] GET http://localhost:3000/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 9ms]
[23:41:40.205] Unknown property 'user-select'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:75
[23:41:40.209] Unknown property 'box-sizing'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:257
[23:41:40.213] Expected declaration but found '*'.  Skipped to next declaration. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:418
[23:41:40.223] Expected color but found 'auto'.  Expected color but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Expected end of value but found '-webkit-focus-ring-color'.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:482
[23:41:40.236] Error in parsing value for 'width'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:508
[23:41:40.263] Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-search-decoration'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:568
[23:41:40.275] @page rule not allowed within @media or @-moz-document rule. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:624
[23:41:40.674] Unknown property 'word-break'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:1414
[23:41:40.684] Unknown property 'transition'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:1557
[23:41:40.694] Expected color but found 'thin'.  Expected color but found 'dotted'.  Expected color but found '    '.  Expected end of value but found '    '.  Error in parsing value for 'outline'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:1578
[23:41:40.706] Expected end of value but found '    '.  Error in parsing value for 'margin-top'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:1588
[23:41:40.743] Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-ms-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:1658
[23:41:40.752] Unknown pseudo-class or pseudo-element '-webkit-input-placeholder'.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:1663
[23:41:40.802] Expected end of value but found '    '.  Error in parsing value for 'padding-right'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:2241
[23:41:40.813] Expected end of value but found '    '.  Error in parsing value for 'padding-left'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:2243
[23:41:40.930] Unknown property '-moz-background-clip'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:3341
[23:41:40.964] Error in parsing value for 'background-image'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:3378
[23:41:41.019] Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:3383
[23:41:41.240] Expected end of value but found '    '.  Error in parsing value for 'background-color'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:3652
[23:41:42.518] Unknown property 'zoom'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:6001
[23:41:42.529] Unrecognized at-rule or error parsing at-rule '@keyframes'. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:6177
[23:41:42.719] Unknown property '-moz-background-size'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:6249
[23:41:42.731] Unknown property 'animation'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:6259
[23:41:43.855] Unknown property '-moz-opacity'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:7946
[23:41:43.867] Expected declaration but found '/'.  Skipped to next declaration. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:7957
[23:41:43.928] Error in parsing value for 'font-style'.  Declaration dropped. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:8135
[23:41:43.955] Selector expected.  Ruleset ignored due to bad selector. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:8221
[23:41:43.966] Unexpected end of file while searching for closing } of invalid rule set. @ http://localhost:3000/b114a8a70a1f97d902da1444cfc95b715b3d5f0b.css:8222
[23:41:44.185] >>>>>>>>>>> renderBodyTemplate @ http://localhost:3000/client/web/views/main/body/body.js?2a5333f86996eda61d279462ae073ad6780f6ea7:1
[23:41:44.220] Can only call _ensureIndex on server collections @ http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo-livedata.js?cf17a2975aa7445f0db2377c2af07e5efc240958:577
[23:41:44.244] >>>>>>>>>>> startup @ http://localhost:3000/client/web/index.js?2f61fe43bd100b1f25522fc44d3eb356e0da068a:5
[23:41:44.275] Template[Session.get("ContentTemplate")] is not a function @ http://localhost:3000/client/web/views/content/content.js?b24eeb8c923cf2032ed9529256717bc171000d56:11
[23:41:44.290] GET http://localhost:3000/sockjs/info?cb=7_bhz4xmt3 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 3ms]
[23:41:44.337] GET http://localhost:3000/sockjs/798/c25yv35x/websocket [HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols 7ms]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a ton of CSS errors. However, there are a few Javascript errors that are probably preventing your page from rendering:

```
[23:41:44.185] >>>>>>>>>>> renderBodyTemplate @ http://localhost:3000/client/web/views/main/body/body.js?2a5333f86996eda61d279462ae073ad6780f6ea7:1
[23:41:44.220] Can only call _ensureIndex on server collections @ http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo-livedata.js?cf17a2975aa7445f0db2377c2af07e5efc240958:577
```

You've probably declared some server/client collections and failed to call `_ensureIndex` on only the server code.

```
[23:41:44.244] >>>>>>>>>>> startup @ http://localhost:3000/client/web/index.js?2f61fe43bd100b1f25522fc44d3eb356e0da068a:5
[23:41:44.275] Template[Session.get("ContentTemplate")] is not a function @ http://localhost:3000/client/web/views/content/content.js?b24eeb8c923cf2032ed9529256717bc171000d56:11
```

You probably just updated to Meteor 0.8 (Blaze) and the way to use templates to render HTML has changed: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze

**Update**: according to the new post you added, the problem is that templates are no longer functions that render HTML given data arguments. Please refer to the third point in this section: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#templatefoo-is-not-a-function-and-does-not-return-a-string

Comment: Please check once the above code and what are things can change in meteor 0.8 version.I didn't get any idea so can you please suggest me.@Andrew Mao

Comment: @Venkat you will have to completely change the way you do that in 0.8. See the updated link.

Comment: Yes,But actually i need to change the above my post.Can you please change the above one to 0.8 meteor Version.@Andrew Mao